# How to use JPL (the java prolog interface of swi-prolog) with Eclipse?

Tags: java, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

I donwnloaded swi-prolog 7.2.2.

I copied the jpl.dll file (under swipl/bin) to system32.

I created a new project in Eclipse and I put the jpl.jar in the path (like any other jar files).

Then, when I try to launch this code:

```
package main_package;

import org.jpl7.Query;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "consult('lib\rules.pl')";
        Query q = new Query(s); //the exception is thrown here
        System.out.println(q.hasSolution());

    }

}
```

I obtain:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Windows\System32\jpl.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform**

I read online that maybe I should change the java vm to his 32 bit version. I tried it by going to *Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs* and change the vm to the one under program x86 folder, but it did not help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Install the 64-bit version of SWI-Prolog (http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable) and add the new directory to path.

Answer (score 0):

Although the directory name

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

leads us to believe that it contains the 32-bit versions of DLLs and programs, it does not. In fact, on 64-bit Windows systems it contains the 64-bit versions. The directory name was not changed due to compatibility reasons.

If a 32-bit program is started on a 64-bit Windows system, the operating system maps the directory

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64
```

to be the `System32` directory. So you have to place your 32-bit DLL into the `SysWOW64` directory.

Summary:

1. The directory `System32` contains the 64-bit versions of the files.
2. The directory `SysWOW64` contains the 32-bit versions of the files.

Side note:

The "WOW" part in the directory name `SysWOW64` means "Windows on Windows".

Link:

[Wikipedia article about WOW64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64)